# How to Pause Notification PendingIntent for some time[Android]

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

In my android application i am using status bar notification to give the user short cut to relaunch the application when user is not in the application.

I have implemented this functionality using android NotificationManager.

What i want to implement is on some events i don't wan PendingIntent to be launched.
Meaning, when user taps on the Status bar notification icon nothing should happen it should as it launch my application again when user taps on it.

Can we some how pause or remove the PendingIntent?

I have tried it using AlarmManager as following:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(intent);
```

and also I tried to set `Notification.contentIntent` to NULL but it also do not work.

How should I implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you set the notification at the first place? Post the code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can cancel the PendingIntent using the method that you specified. You need to be sure that the Intent passed to `cancel()` is equal to the original Intent. The action, data, and category of the two Intents must be *exactly* the same. Please see the documentation for [IntentFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) for a fuller explanation.